# How do we filter the rows from pandas dataframe whose index values ends with 'x'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How do we filter the rows from pandas dataframe whose index values ends with 'x'

I am new to pandas and I am not able to get the answer from the documentation.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`endswith`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/endswith.html) function to get a boolean result for matching index and call under [`df.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) which filters only those rows whose index ends with `x`:

```
df.loc[df.index.str.endswith('x',na=False)]
```

Or just:

```
df[df.index.str.endswith('x',na=False)] #thanks Mohit and Jez for inputs
```